# How to configure Unity under proxy

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm trying to use Unity but unfortunately it stacks on the "Checking your license" phase. I know there might be a proxy issue. I want to know how to configure proxy to work with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set 2 envs.

**http_proxy: [your http proxy]:[port]**

**https_proxy: [your https proxy]:[port]**

Answer (score 0):

For those ending up here like me and wondering how to do this easily, there's an easy way to set this directly in C#

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("http_proxy", "your_proxy_adr:your_proxy_port");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("https_proxy", "your_proxy_adr:your_proxy_port");
```

running this before any HTTP calls will make sure this is set for your current process.